# How do I get the username from user_id in a MySQL database?

Tags: php

I want to create a profile system for my website. Every user has its own unique ID. I want to get the username from the ID (in the URL). I can get the ID, but how do I get the username?

My current code:

```
<?php

include 'Connection.php';
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri_parts = parse_url( $uri );
$ID=$uri_parts[ "query" ];

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".(int)$ID);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo "

<div class='divider-right' style='width:484px;float:left;'>
        <div class='profileUser-Name'>
            $userRow['username'] Profile
        </div>
</div>
";
?>
```

Comment: `$userRow[username] Profile` or `{$userRow['username']} Profile`

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Put {} around $userRow['username']

```
{$userRow['username']}
```

Or concatenate

```
 " . $userRow ['username'] . "
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe when running the mysqli_fetch_array command, it takes in a second parameter called "MYSQLI_ASSOC", which then allows you to index the array using the term you want, such as "username". Try that out. Oh, also, you should be using mysqli.